# Checking a box in one checkboxgroup disables or hides a box with the same value in another checkboxgroup

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have an `ExtJS` window that has 2 separate panels with `checkboxgroups`.
 They both show the same values, but user cannot select the same item from both `checkboxgroups`.

I want to deal with this a little fancier than just checking and alerting a warning in both `ckeckboxgroup's` listeners when user selects already selected value in another `checkboxgroup`.

To avoid alerts, I want to either hide or disable the box.

I have tried to add **`hidden:true`** or **`disabled:true`** but no luck:

```
Ext.create('widget.window', 
{
    title       : 'Select a value',
    draggable   : true,
    modal       : true,
    closable    : true,
    closeAction : 'destroy',
    width       : 400,
    height      : 350,
    layout: 
    {
        type  : 'hbox',
        align : 'stretch'
    },
    items : 
    [{
        xtype      : 'panel',
        title      : 'Success',
        autoScroll : true,
        flex       : 1,
        items      :
        [{
            xtype     : 'checkboxgroup',
            itemId    : 'success',
            columns   : 1,
            vertical  : true,
            items     : yes_checkbox,
            listeners : 
            {
                change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts)
                {
                    // newValue.rb
                }
            }
        }] 
    },
    {
        xtype      : 'panel',
        id         : 'panel_failure',
        title      : 'failure',
        autoScroll : true,
        flex       : 1,
        items      :
        [{
            xtype     : 'checkboxgroup',
            itemId    : 'failure',
            columns   : 1,
            vertical  : true,
            items     : no_checkbox,
            listeners : 
            {
                change: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts)
                {
                    // newValue.rb

                }
            }
        }],

    }],
});
```

**I tried to get the `panel_failed` like `Ext.getCmp('panel_failed').items.add(//something here)` inside the `change` listener.** But I cannot figure out whether the `add()` is the right method, and if is, what is the format to write inside the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `itemId` of all your checkboxes and then will be easy to select and disable them with `setDisabled(true)`;

Comment: should i use down(#itemId) then?